# Coalesce not working in an update join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, coalesce

I have an update query where I am trying to find the net interest from multiple accounts on three different transaction tables deposits, checks, and general entries. The problem I'm running into is when one of those tables has no entries for a loan number to an interest account the select returns nothing and subsequently displays a null in the production table too. Negating the other tables if they return rows from interest account. If all three tables have a row for interest the query works fine.

Here's the code:

```
UPDATE Prod
  SET Prod.InterestSpread = (T1.Amount+T2.Amount-T3.Amount)
FROM dbo.Production_Pipeline as Prod
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT LoanNumber,COALESCE(SUM(JournalLineAmount),0)as Amount
  FROM dbo.GeneralLedger
  WHERE (JournalLineAccountRefListID = 'BB0000-1103842703' 
  OR JournalLineAccountRefListID = '800001DA-1202763722')
) AS T1
ON T1.LoanNumber = Prod.LoanNumber
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT LoanNumber,COALESCE(SUM(DepositLineAmount),0)as Amount
  FROM dbo.DepositLedger
  WHERE ( DepositLineAccountRefListID = 'BB0000-1103842703' 
  OR DepositLineAccountRefListID = '800001DA-1202763722')
) AS T2
ON T2.LoanNumber = Prod.LoanNumber
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT LoanNumber,COALESCE(SUM(ExpenseLineAmount),0) AS Amount
  FROM dbo.CheckLedger
  WHERE(ExpenseLineAccountRefListID = '800002B4-1308771936'
    OR ExpenseLineAccountRefListID = 'D30000-1105022008'
    OR ExpenseLineAccountRefListID = '8000029E-1283179936'
    OR ExpenseLineAccountRefListID = 'BB0000-1103842703'
    OR ExpenseLineAccountRefListID = '800001DA-1202763722')
) AS T3
ON T3.LoanNumber = Prod.LoanNumber
```

So an inccorect result update looks like
T1Amount: 496.08
T2Amount:
T3Amount: 373.92
Interest Spread: NULL

I've done some quite a bit of research on this site but, have been unable to apply your wisdom to my specific issue so any help here would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What if you do not have a matching LoanNumber for the T2 sub-query? Don't you want to use a left join in this case?

Comment: Yup. I agree I changed it but I'm still having the issue. That's got me thinking though. Since no result is being returned the COALESCE wouldn't really come into effect because there is no match with the loan number.

Comment: You have got your answer below. Together with the left joins you will have your `InterestSpread` updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `COALESCE` statement to outside of the `JOIN` and remove it from the subqueries:

```
UPDATE Prod
SET Prod.InterestSpread =
      COALESCE(T1.Amount,0)+COALESCE(T2.Amount,0)-COALESCE(T3.Amount,0)
...
```

The problem is your subqueries return no results, thus coalesce inside of that cannot be applied to the field.  By using it outside of the outer join, you ensure if the result is null, it converts properly.

Comment: Yup. Your correct, thank you so much sgeddes and cha. The wheels were spinning but, you go me there a lot faster!